# XPath token syntax in Kettle 5.0.1

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle

This is a bit of a beginner question, but so far I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm using the "Get Data from XML" input transformation in Kettle, and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the syntax for XPath.

Looking in all of the sample transformation files, it seems like XPath is specified in a fairly straightforward way.

If I have an xml file that has:

```
<A>
 <B>
   <C att1='fruit' att2='banana'>
   </C>
   <C att1='vegetable' att2='lettuce'>
   </C>   
 </B>
</A>
```

And I want to get att1 'fruit', I just type the following into the Field XPath:

```
A/B/C/@att1
```

However, Kettle won't accept this syntax. It insists on writing the XPath as:

```
*[name()='A']/*[name()='B']/*[name()='C']/@att1
```

This is fine. However, once the XPaths get more complicated, for example when I want to use tokens, I'm a bit lost as to how to write it.

Say now I want to read in the value of att2, but only if att1 is 'vegetable'. I would write it like this, using a token:

```
A/B/C[@att1='vegetable']/@att2
```

But how would I write this in Kettle's syntax?

Also, not sure if this is relevant, but I am running Kettle 5.0.1 on Windows 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could there be namespace issues?  I.e., is there a namespace declaration in your document?

Comment: It looks like there was a namespace declaration in <A>.. it says <A xlmns="http://website">.. does that also affect child nodes? and if so, how would I specify tokens in the XPath?

Comment: Here is [some info about namespace declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration). You either have to set up a default namespace for your XPath expressions, or a namespace prefix that you'd have to use with your XPath steps, like `ns:A/ns:B/ns:C/@att1`.  However, I have no idea what Kettle even is, so I can not help at all with the configuration. Possibly [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/70155-namespace-problems#post529890) can give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
A/B/C/@att1
```

gets transformed into:

```
*[name()='A']/*[name()='B']/*[name()='C']/@att1
```

then

```
A/B/C[@att1='vegetable']/@att2
```

should be:

```
*[name()='A']/*[name()='B']/*[name()='C' and @att1='vegetable']/@att2
```

However, this strange transformation could be related to how you are using namespaces.

You might want to replace `name()` with `local-name()` or consider